# How to test SimPy simulation code with pytest?

Tags: testing, random, automated-tests, pytest, simpy

I'm using SimPy to write a simple network simulator. I'd like to write some tests (ideally with pytest or similar) to automatically test that my code is doing what it's supposed to do.

My problem is that the simulation contains a lot of randomly generated events (e.g., flow arrivals). Is it possible to test, for example, if my function that randomly generates new flows works correctly (with pytest)? If so, how?

My goal is to write some (unit) tests that I can run automatically with Travis whenever I want to merge new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the random seed in the [random library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) to get reproducable results. Other random libraries that you might use should have the same feature e.g. [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html).